# try-except command does not catch exception with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to catch the exceptions I raise in a function called `callback`.
Here's a simplification of the code.

```
        try:
            logger.info("This message gets logged!!!")
            with Pool() as executor:
                results = executor.map(callback, made_up_list)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

This doesn't seem to work, since any exception raised by callback shows on the terminal.
One interesting thing is if we use the debug mode in an IDE (my case vscode), and put a breakpoint on the `except` line, we never get there, since we remain stuck due to the raised exception. However, if I do `CTRL`+`c`, I stop the process, and then I pass to the `except` line.
It may be worth knowing the callback itself already uses multithreading when doing some computations which will result in raising an exception.

If I change the line order a bit, to:

```
    with Pool() as executor::
        logger.info("This message gets logged!!!")
        try:
            results = executor.map(callback, made_up_list)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

I get a similar undesired result of not catching the exception.

Comment: show your callback as well

Comment: Handle the exception in the callback.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I can't since it's a really big function...

Comment: @KlausD. I'm running this code for test purposes, and I would like to avoid redefining the callback.

Comment: Exceptions do not propagate from external processes. If `callback` raises an exception that doesn't get caught, the process simply exits with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: @chepner Processes that constitute a multiprocessing pool are not supposed to exit just because the task they are running raises an exception; they need to continue to exist in order to run the remaining submitted tasks.

Comment: Good point; I overlooked that `Pool` was being used. But the process still cannot pass the exception itself to the original script, since the OS doesn't know what an exception is or how to represent them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to wrap your callback inside decorator to catch exception and then pass your decorated function inside executor like this

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import update_wrapper

class my_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
        try:
            update_wrapper(self, target)
        except:
            pass

    def __call__(self, args):
        self.target(args)

def func(a):
    print(int(a))

callback = my_decorator(func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as executor:
        logging.info("This message gets logged!!!")
        results = executor.map(callback,[1,2,3, '4', 'a'])
```

Comment: Implementing your answer, gives me: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'decorate_callback.<locals>.fun'`

Comment: Let me correct this.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.  I have edited the code now it will work please change it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not catching an exception (assuming one occurs in your worker function, `callback`. Perhaps this is due to some peculiarity of your IDE. The following code when run from a command line (not an IDE) works as expected:

```py
def callback(x):
    if x == 2:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid value {x}')
    return x ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    made_up_list = [1, 2, 3]

    with Pool() as executor:
        try:
            results = executor.map(callback, made_up_list)
            print(results)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Got exception:',  e)
```

Prints:

```None
Got exception: Invalid value 2
```

You might see if the following works, which has the additional benefit of getting a `results` list for those tasks that have completed normally, i.e. if you want to catch individual exceptions as well as the results of successful completions that occur in your worker function `callback` in your main process, then you could use the `Pool.imap` method instead of `Pool.map`:

```py
def callback(x):
    if x == 2:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid value {x}')
    return x ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    made_up_list = [1, 2, 3]

    with Pool() as executor:
        results = []
        it = executor.imap(callback, made_up_list)
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except Exception as e:
                result = e
                print('Got exception:',  e)
            results.append(result) # Include Exception instances
        print(results)
```

Prints:

```None
Got exception: Invalid value 2
[1, ValueError('Invalid value 2'), 9]
```

**If this makes no difference, then you need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).**